# How Do I Add Custom Properties To CodeDOM Output

Tags: c#, codedom

I'm trying to add custom properties to CodeDOM output, such as file version, author, etc. I'm unsure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the file version, you have to use `AssemblyFileVersion` attribute.
See the [example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623717/setting-file-version-for-a-codedom-file)

```
CodeCompileUnit unit = CreateMyUnit();
var attribute = new CodeAttributeDeclaration(
    new CodeTypeReference(typeof(AssemblyFileVersionAttribute)));
attribute.Arguments.Add(
    new CodeAttributeArgument(
        new CodePrimitiveExpression("1.1.1.1")));
unit.AssemblyCustomAttributes.Add(attribute);
```

As for the author, you may do the similar thing. See the [MSDN assembly attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4w8c1y2s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

**EDIT:**

You need add the references.

```
using System.CodeDom;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
```

Comment: You have to add necessary references.This is because there is no such attribute existing. Check the MSDN link I gave to you. Please use other attribute such as copyright etc.

Comment: You have to do two things. A: show your code. B: follow the example on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404245%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Try to remove the line `[assembly: AssemblyCompanyAttribute("Test")]`. I don't see MSDN example having such a declarative code.

Comment: It changed nothing at all. Now I'm back where I started.